# how to get .ptp file from TexMaker?

Tags: editors

I need a .ptp file format (PCTeX project file) from my .tex file, I'm using texmaker editor to compile my work, and it didn't generate the .ptp file, only .aux, .pdf, .log, .syntex.gz. I'm sorry my question is quite newbie. Thanks.

Comment: What's a `ptp` file? Do you mean `ppt` (Microsoft Powerpoint)? LaTeX does not make either `ptp` or `ppt` files. It only outputs either `pdf` (usually) or `dvi`.

Comment: from what I search ptp is a file which generated automatically by PCTex editor, which stands for PCTex Project file, is it possible to generate that from texmaker? because PCTex is not a free apps.

Comment: That sounds like a custom project format for the PCTex editor (I've never used this). It probably just includes settings related to what files are included in the project and how to build it. I'd be surprised if TeXMaker could export such a file. But why bother? Presumably PCTeX only needs the `tex` and any resources and it can happily import and use them.

Comment: I need it for some reason, but from your answer, I assume I need PCTex for that to generate it, thanks! could you post your reply as an answer please?

Comment: I can give an answer, but someone who has used PCTeX can probably be more authoritative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptp` files are a custom project file format used by the PCTeX editor. It contains names of files used in the project and which `TeX` format should be used to build it. TeXMaker (probably) can not export to this format.

However, I notice form a bit of googling that the format is just a simple text file. Perhaps you can make one by hand.

At its simplest, it seems like they look like this:

```
# PCTeX Project File, Version 1.1
    name: myproject
    texformat: LATEX
myproject.tex
```

Google for [pctex project file filetype:ptp](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pctex+project+file+filetype%3Aptp) for some more examples.